# play a single beep (beep.js)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i'm trying to create a "generative score" using [beep.js](https://github.com/stewdio/beep.js) based on some map data i have. i am using `new Beep.Voice` as placeholder for notes associated to specific types of data (7 voices total). as data is displayed, a voice should be played. i'm doing things pretty "brute force" so far and i'd like it to be cleaner:

```js
// in the data processing function
voice = voices[datavoice]
voice.play()
setTimeout(function(){killVoice(voice)}, 20)

// and the killvoice:
function killVoice(voice) {
    voice.pause()
}
```

i'd like to just "play" the voice, assuming it would have a duration of, say, 20ms (basically just beep on data). i saw the `duration` property of voices but couldn't make them work.

the code is here (uses grunt/node/coffeescript):

https://github.com/mgiraldo/inspectorviz/blob/master/app/scripts/main.coffee

this is how it looks like so far:

https://vimeo.com/126519613

Comment: i saw the duration property of voices but couldn't make them work. Can you show, what you mean?

Comment: it's undocumented in the readme. I found it messing around in the console. maybe it is related with score durations (see Composing in [the readme](https://github.com/stewdio/beep.js/blob/master/README.md))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget everything I said ;)

Inspired by your inquiry—and Sam’s old pull request—I’ve just completed a big ADSR push which includes support for `Voice` durations. So now with the latest [Beep.js](https://github.com/stewdio/beep.js) getting a quick “chiptune-y” chirp can be done like this:

```
var voice = new Beep.Voice( '4D♭' )
    .setOscillatorType( 'square' )
    .setAttackDuration( 0 )
    .setDecayDuration( 0 )
    .setSustainDuration( 0.002 )
    .setReleaseDuration( 0 )
    .play()
```

I’ve even included an [ADSR ASCII-art diagram](https://github.com/stewdio/beep.js/blob/master/beep/Beep.Voice.js#L143) in the new `Beep.Voice.js` file for easy referencing. I hope this helps!

Comment: there seems to be a browser issue? works fine in Chrome and Safari. doesn't in Firefox (Mac OS 10.10.3)

Comment: re Firefox: it will slowly go "weird" after a while… hard to explain but becomes evident when changing tabs, zooming and such: http://mgiraldo.github.io/inspectorviz/

Answer (score 3):

The reason `Beep.Voice.duration` is undocumented in the READ ME is because it’s not finished yet! ;) There’s a line in the source code that literally says [“Right now these do nothing; just here as a stand-in for the future.”](https://github.com/stewdio/beep.js/blob/master/beep/Beep.Voice.js#L131) This applies to `.duration`, `.attack`, etc. There’s a pull request to implement some of this functionality [here](https://github.com/stewdio/beep.js/pull/4) but I’ve had to make some significant structural changes since that request was submitted; will need to take a closer look soon once I’ve finished fixing some larger structural issues. (It’s in the pipeline, I promise!)

Your approach in the meantime seems right on the money. I’ve reduced it a bit here and made it 200 milliseconds—rather than 20—so I could here it ring a bit more:

```
var voice = new Beep.Voice('4D♭')
voice.play()
setTimeout( function(){ voice.pause() }, 200 )
```

I saw you were using some pretty low notes in your sample code, like '1A♭' for example. If you’re just testing this out on normal laptop speakers—a position I am often myself in—you might find the tone is too low for your speakers; you’ll either hear a tick or dead silence. So don’t worry: it’s not a bug, just a hardware issue :)

Comment: thanks. I have that low value because I want a very “chiptune-y” sound :)